# Como ter suporte a transações com JUnit e Demoiselle 2.4.2

Tags: demoiselle, junit, transações

Tenho uma aplicação cujos testes unitários estão em pleno funcionamento, exceto para operações de gravação no banco de dados. Nenhum dado é gravado. Ao forçar um flush, recebi a mensagem indicando que nenhuma transação estava em andamento, mesmo estando o método do BusinessController anotado com `@Transactional`. Tudo funciona corretamente na execução normal da aplicação dentro do JBoss, apenas nos casos de teste o problema se manifesta. Meu `persistence.xml` segue abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="restaurante-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>...</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@servidororacle" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="schema" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

O que está faltando?

### Update 1

Conforme orientação, o arquivo `/src/test/resources/META-INF/beans.xml` foi alterado para conter a classe do interceptor do Demoiselle, como abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
 </beans>
```

O comportamento efetivamente mudou, pois antes a chamada do método `insert()` do meu `BusinessController` (`restauranteUnidadeBC`) não executava nenhuma operação no BD, mas agora eu recebo uma exceção com a seguinte mensagem:

`Você está tentando obter um objeto não reconhecido pelo CDI via Beans.getReference(javax.transaction.UserTransaction)`

Aparentemente falta ainda alguma coisa. O código do teste segue abaixo:

```
@Test
public void shouldAbrirCaixaComUsuarioLogado() {
    // Arrange
    Pessoa operador = pessoaBC.byChave("11111111111"); 
    RestauranteUnidade unidade = new RestauranteUnidade("Teste");
    unidade.getOperadores().add(operador);
    unidade = restauranteUnidadeBC.insert(unidade); // <<<< EXCEÇÃO AQUI!!!
    BigDecimal valorAbertura = new BigDecimal(10.50);

    // Act
    ...
}
```

A primeira invocação, que obtém o operador funciona dentro do esperado.

### Update 2

Visando dar mais subsídios, forneço o trace de exceções correspondente ao erro:

```
br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.DemoiselleException: Você está tentando obter um objeto não reconhecido pelo CDI via Beans.getReference(javax.transaction.UserTransaction)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.Beans.getReference(Beans.java:132)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.JTATransaction.getDelegate(JTATransaction.java:65)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.JTATransaction.isActive(JTATransaction.java:77)
    at br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor.initiate(TransactionalInterceptor.java:135)
    at ... diversas outras chamadas
```

Por este trace conseguimos perceber que o problema se manifesta em um método da classe `JTATransaction`.

Foi comentado a respeito da indisponibilidade de alguma dependência necessária. Segue abaixo uma versão simplificada do `pom.xml` para avaliação:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    ... divresas definições 

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
        <artifactId>demoiselle-jsf-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        ... diversas dependências próprias
        <!-- Dependências do SERPRO Demoiselle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ... outras dependências específicas do projeto incluindo Hibernate

        <!-- Dependências para suporte ao JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>simple-jndi</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoiselle-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    ... definições de plug-ins do Maven    
</project>
```

A suspeita a respeito de uma dependência faltante parece justificada, pois a título de teste eu adicionei ao projeto de teste uma classe implementando a interface `UserTransaction` e o erro de CDI parou de ocorrer. Como a classe era *dummy*, não tive mais erro, mas voltei à situação onde as operações de alteração de BD não têm efeito.

Outra evidência é o log do console do Eclipse:

```
08:12:50,144  INFO Version:207 - WELD-000900 1.1.8 (Final)
08:12:50,418  INFO Bootstrap:245 - WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
08:12:50,699  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - Ligando os motores do Demoiselle 2.4.2
08:12:50,702  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - BeanManager disponível através do utilitário br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.Beans
08:12:52,510  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - O Demoiselle 2.4.2 decolou
```

Reitero que a aplicação funciona a contento, o problema somente se manifesta no contexto do JUnit.

### Update 3

Após a remoção da dependência de `demoiselle-jta`, nenhuma diferença perceptível foi observada, o problema persiste. Abaixo o log do console desde o início até o fim da operação:

```
08:42:01,197  INFO Version:207 - WELD-000900 1.1.8 (Final)
08:42:01,518  INFO Bootstrap:245 - WELD-000101 Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
08:42:01,813  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - Ligando os motores do Demoiselle 2.4.2
08:42:01,818  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - BeanManager disponível através do utilitário br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.util.Beans
08:42:03,678  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - O Demoiselle 2.4.2 decolou
08:42:06,402  INFO Version:24 - Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
08:42:11,643  INFO Version:37 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
08:42:11,697  INFO Version:41 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.7.Final}
08:42:11,717  INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
08:42:11,724  INFO Environment:342 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
08:42:13,585  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:96 - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
08:42:13,891  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:130 - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
08:42:13,892  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:133 - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
08:42:13,893  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:147 - HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@aikanahml.cce.ufpr.br:1521:hml01]
08:42:13,894  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:152 - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=restaurante_test, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
08:42:15,132  INFO Dialect:125 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
08:42:15,297  INFO TransactionFactoryInitiator:73 - HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
08:42:15,332  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
08:42:35,107  INFO LoggerProducer:209 - Gerenciador de entidades criado a partir da unidade de persistência "restaurante-ds".
Hibernate: alguns selects necessários que antecedem o INSERT
...
>>> Aqui ocorreu a exceção, mas nenhuma mensagem é registrada no console, apenas em debug é possível rastrear a exceção e inspecionar seus detalhes

08:44:09,578  INFO CoreBootstrap:209 - Desligando os motores do Demoiselle 2.4.2
08:44:09,579  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:156 - HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:oracle:thin:@aikanahml.cce.ufpr.br:1521:hml01]
```

Comment: algum progresso após o update 2 da resposta?

Comment: @JoaquimOliveira, desculpe, não percebi que a resposta havia recebido atualização. Alterei o pom para definir o `scope` da dependência de JTA para `compile` e a dependência de JPA ficou com o `scope` configurado para `test`, mas isso não modificou o comportamento do problema. Eu não havia me atentado do conflito de dependências porque isso não afeta a execução da aplicação, apenas dos testes. Em resumo, continuo na mesma.

Comment: @JoaquimOliveira, removi a dependência de JTA do `pom`. A aplicação executa sem problema, mesmo que no `persistence.xml` eu tenha a configuração de tipo da persistence unit para JTA. O problema não se modificou. Quando eu tirei a dependência de JPA e deixei apenas a de JTA, a aplicação passou a não mais ser iniciada.

Comment: @JoaquimOliveira, retificando, após remover a dependência do demoiselle-jpa passei a ter um erro um uma parte da aplicação, no caso um DAO dependente de `JPACrudExtended<>`, durante um processo de update. Assim sendo, tive que recolocar a dependência de demoiselle-jpa.

Comment: minha sugestão era retirar a **demoiselle-jta**, supondo que sua aplicação não necessita de transações distribuídas.

Comment: @JoaquimOliveira: removi a dependência do `demoiselle-jta`, mas o problema não parece ter se modificado. No trecho de código onde faço um insert recebo uma exceção com a mensagem `Você está tentando obter um objeto não reconhecido pelo CDI via Beans.getReference(javax.transaction.UserTransaction)`. Mais alguma ideia? Vocês já realizaram testes unitários com operações transacionais no BD? o Demoiselle realmente suporta esse cenário?

Comment: veja se o novo update da resposta ajuda. Abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As anotações de transação são processadas por um interceptor do JavaEE (`br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor`).

Verifique se ele:

1) Ele está declarado corretamente no `src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml` da sua aplicação e que **não existe o mesmo arquivo** no `src/test/resources/META-INF/` ou

2) Existem o arquivo em ambos os diretórios e ele tem o mesmo conteúdo. Lembre-se que, durante os testes, o arquivo que prevalece é o do `src/test/resources/META-INF/`

### Update 1

Aparentemente, o CDI não está conseguindo achar uma implementação da classe `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` para injetar. [Geralmente, estas classes ficam dentro das dependências](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.3.4/html/transacao.html#d0e399) **`demoiselle-jpa`** ou **`demoiselle-jta`**. Verifique se umas dessas dependências está declarada no `pom.xml` do seu projeto.

Outra coisa que pode estar atrapalhando é a existência de um `persistence.xml` mal configurado no diretório `src/test/resources`. Da mesma forma que o `beans.xml`, se houver este arquivo nesta localização, ele prevalece sobre o `src/main/resources` durante a execução dos testes unitários.

### Update 2

@AlexSC, a partir da documentação do Demoiselle, entendo que você deve escolhar **uma** das duas estratégias possíveis: JPA ou JTA. Percebi que você tem as duas declaradas no seu `pom.xml`.

Sugiro testar somente com uma delas e remover a outra dependência. Lembrando que [de acordo com a documentação](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.3.4/html/transacao.html#d0e448), caso escolha JTA, você precisa:

- Configurar no seu `persistence.xml` o atributo `transaction-type="JTA"` na `persistence-unit` e
- Incluir a propriedade `hibernate.transaction.jta.platform` apontando para classe correta.

### Update 3

O Demoiselle possui um arquétipo Maven, `demoiselle-jsf-jpa`, que traz um teste unitário com acesso a BD. Minha sugestão é você criar um outro projeto utilizando o arquétipo como base e verificar as diferenças de configuração entre ele e seu projeto.

O catálogo de arquétipos está disponível em http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/repository/archetype-catalog.xml.

Comment: A orientação parece estar no caminho certo, mas creio que ainda falte algo. Adicionei detalhes na questão. Obrigado!

Comment: @AlexSC, o seu teste unitário executa no Oracle?

Comment: sim ele executa no Oracle

Comment: Adicionei mais alguns detalhes à pergunta. Aproveito para informar que o `beans.xml` de cada projeto é diferente. no caso dos testes, tenho uma referência ao interceptor JavaEE de transação provida pelo Demoiselle (`br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor`), fato que não ocorre no `beans.xml` da aplicação

Comment: a dica de estudar o projeto de exemplo Bookmark foi feliz. Nele pude perceber diferenças existentes nos arquivos `beans.xml` e `demoiselle.properties`que se mostraram *absolutamente mandatórias* para que tudo funcionasse. Obrigado!